# React firestore inconsistency while fetching data using onSnapshot

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

i'm trying to fetch data from firestore using the `onSnapshot` listener, but **i'm getting old values instead of new updated/updating values, even though I change the data manually from firebase console, there is no effect on frontend react-native app** i.e. the onSnapshot is kinda behaving weird... does anyone have any clue what might be causing this?

In a component:-

```js
const { group } = useSelectedGroup();
const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
        if (group === '') return;
        const unsub = firestore
            .collection(`groups/${group}/scorebar`)
            .onSnapshot(
                snapshot => {
                    if (!user) return;
                    if (snapshot.empty) return;
                    const snapshotData = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const docData = {
                            [doc.id]: doc.data(),
                        };
                        return docData;
                    });
                    setData(snapshotData);
                },
                error => console.log(error),
            );
        return () => unsub();
    }, [group]);
```

Below are my firestore security rules related to the path above in case...

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // other rules...
    match /groups/{groupId}{
      allow create: if !resourceExists();
      allow delete: if resourceExists() && isGroupOwner();
      allow read: if !resourceExists() || isGroupMember() || isGroupInvitee();
      allow update: if resourceExists() && (isGroupAdmin() || isGroupStatusUpdate());
      
       match /scorebar/{memberId} {
        allow read: if isAuthorized();
        allow write: if isAuthorized();
      }
    }
    // other rules...
  }
}
```

And yes data/docs inside the collection `groups/{groupId}/scorebar` exists, I double checked by printing the path in app and pasting it in firebase console which showed me 2 non-empty docs.

I've got no clue here why is this inconsistency. My frontend is not picking up the latest values of the fields inside the docs whenever a change happen in any of the doc inside `scorebar` collection.

Can someone pls provide some insights regarding this issue?

environment info:

```
"expo": "^46.0.0",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.6",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "~15.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "~15.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "~15.4.0",
```

Pls ask for any additional info required. I'd be happy to share!

**UPDATE: 1**

It maybe due to the reason that when I change the group, the old snapshot listener is still active so that is why the new snapshot listener doens't work..? For that I did the following changes but it is still the same:

```js
const [previousListener, setPreviousListener] = useState<any | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
        if (group === '') return;
        if (previousListener) {
            previousListener();
        }
        const unsub = firestore
            .collection(`groups/${group}/scorebar`)
            .onSnapshot(
                snapshot => {
                    if (!user) return;
                    if (snapshot.empty) return;
                    const snapshotData = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const docData = {
                            [doc.id]: doc.data(),
                        };
                        return docData;
                    });
                    setData(snapshotData);
                },
                error => console.log(error),
            );
        setPreviousListener(() => unsub);
        return () => unsub();
    }, [group]);
```

But still I mean, if it were to work, it would have fetched the latest values from firestore db on first render of useEffect, but still it fetches some old values and not the latest updated ones...

**UPDATE: 2**

I tried to replace fetch ability from `.onSnapshot` to `.get` but now It's not even fetching the data, it never goes below the `awat firestore().collection(...)` line... this is weird

```js
useEffect(() => {
        if (group === '') return;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                console.log('ref path: ', `groups/${group}/scorebar`) // yes log, tried to paste it in firebase console and showed me the collection with 2 docs
                const ref = await firestore.collection(`groups/${group}/scorebar`).get();
                console.log('ref size: ', ref.size); // no log
                const snapshotData = ref.docs.map(doc => {
                    const docData = {
                        [doc.id]: doc.data(),
                    };
                    return docData;
                });
                console.log('SNAPSHOT DATA: ', snapshotData); // obviously no log
                setData(snapshotData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('firestore err: ', error); // no log
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [group]);
```

Comment: Confirm that the documents within the `groups/{groupId}/scorebar` collection are actually being updated. You can try adding a timestamp field to the documents and observe if the timestamps change when you manually update the data from the Firebase console. Review your codebase for any other code that might be interacting with the Firestore collection or the same documents. Ensure that there are no conflicting read or write operations happening concurrently. Make sure you are using the latest version of the `@react-native-firebase/firestore package.`